# Error: connection to server at "localhost" (::1), port 5432 failed: FATAL: database "UContinental" does not exist

Tags: sql, postgresql

Estoy tratando de correr un script en postgresql para crear una base de datos, el script es el siguiente:

```
CREATE DATABASE UContinental;

\c UContinental


CREATE TABLE PAIS(
    ID_PAIS SERIAL NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY,
    NOMBRE_PAIS VARCHAR(20) NOT NULL
);
```

Cuando ejecuto el comando \i con la dirección donde se encuentra el script anterior me sale el siguiente error:

error: \connect: connection to server at "localhost" (::1), port 5432 failed: FATAL:  database "UContinental" does not exist.

No sé por qué sucede esto.

Comment: verificaste que el puerto de tu base de datos sea el que aparece ahi?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Estas creando la base de datos `UContinental` y PostgreSQL automaticamente convierte el nombre a minuscula si no la pones entre comillas dobles "" y luego intentas conectarte a `UContinental` con mayúscula, te recomiendo que uses siempre minúsculas en PostgreSQL, puede evitarte más de una molestia, aunque si puedes hacerlo en mayúscula, pero vas a tener que estar al tanto de ese detalle

por ejemplo:

```
CREATE DATABASE ucontinental;

\c ucontinental


CREATE TABLE pais(
    id_pais SERIAL NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY,
    nombre_pais VARCHAR(20) NOT NULL
);
```